# Running code when /bin/sh has no rights

Tags: account-restrictions, restricted-shell

I've obtained a shell on an embeded device, a `/bin/sh` shell, but it is extremely limited; It just allows me to run a few commands with specific arguments, like `ifconfig`, or `iptables`, or `cat` (but not `cat whateverIwant`, only cat `/proc/cpuusage` for example), I've been able to bypass this shell, and execute any command, or kind of; basically I can try to run any command (lets say, `ping` for example) but `sh` would not have rights to do it.

Errors:
Trying to write to an existing file

```
/bin/sh: cannot create /bin/ping: Text file busy
```

Trying to run ping

```
/bin/sh: Access Denied.
```

So the scenario is that I can run only very specific useless commands, and also I've been able to write to files and to read filenames (not read files), note that, I can't write certain files, i.e. to binaries being used, but I can write new files. The only idea I have that would help me running code is using some kind of "dll hijacking" method like it is done in windows, but I don't know if this is even doable.

EDIT: Additional Info -> The device has 2 usb ports, and has a ftp service. I connect using telnet.

Comment: It is better to give us full commands, not just the output.  Also, although there is a security side to a limited shell you may get better answers on unix.SE.  (you may flag your own question and ask it to be moved)

Answer (score 0):

Try running your code in /tmp. You can wget your code here, make it executable and run it.

Comment: That won't work for several reasons; 1. I can't wget, the command exists but as said, I have no rights to use it. 2. Even I could use it, i can't use chmod